# Don't have a default resource group in IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am using a lite account, where there should be a default resource group.
However, there is nothing in manage > resource groups.
Definitely, I can not create a new one in a lite account.
How can I solve this problem?

By the way, I have verified IBM account by email

Comment: Not sure where you are looking. What is listed here? https://cloud.ibm.com/account/resource-groups

Comment: Yes, it is account > resource groups. And nothing is listed there. I could not solve the problem, so created another ibm cloud account...In the new account, there is a default resource group...